# Make warning in Checkstyle if field is non private and does not have annotation

Tags: java, eclipse, checkstyle, android-annotations

Is there any way to make warning with Checkstyle if field is non private and it do not have one of annotations?

i.e.:

```
public class Foo {
   private String mBoo; // this is OK
   public String mBad; // it should be warning
   [@Bean][1]
   String mBean; // it is OK
   @Bean
   public String mBean; // it should be warning (because it is public)
}
```

@Edit

There are multiple annotations like @Bean [annotations](https://github.com/excilys/androidannotations/wiki/AvailableAnnotations)